# How to get data from php://input?

Tags: php

I have two scripts:

First to send:

```
$url = "http://localhost/curl2.php";
$data = array('email' => 'test@example.com');
$addr = $url . '?' . http_build_query($data);
$ch = curl_init($addr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_exec($ch);
```

And second to receive:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "PUT") {

    $data = array();
    $incoming = file_get_contents("php://input");
    parse_str($incoming, $data);
    echo "Address: " . filter_var($data["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

But variable $incoming is empty. How can I do it? Maybe it has something to do with PUT, but I must use PUT.

Comment: May be obvious, but is $incoming empty?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. $incoming is also empty.

Comment: Use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` instead of appending your fields to the URI (making them GET parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUT is not GET.  Use the URL without a query string and add the data to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`:

```
$url  = "http://localhost/curl2.php";
$data = array('email' => 'test@example.com');
$ch   = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_exec($ch);
```